# Выполнение запроса из нескольких запросов

Tags: c#, sql-server

Имеется следующая функция:

```
private void get_data(string pos, string thick, string diam, int i, int quantity)
   {
        int position = 0;
        int thickness = 0;
        int diametr = 0;
        string connection_string = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        string sql_expression = "SELECT id FROM store_assortment WHERE position_name = '" + pos + "';" +
            "SELECT id FROM thickness WHERE thickness_name = '" + thick + "';" + 
            "SELECT id FROM diametr WHERE diametr_name = '" + diam + "';";
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connection_string);
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql_expression, cn);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            position = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]);
            thickness = Convert.ToInt32(dr[1]);
            diametr = Convert.ToInt32(dr[2]);
        }
        dr.Close();
        cn.Close();
        add_content(i, position, thickness, diametr, quantity);
    }
```

Я думал, что таким нехитрым образом смогу вытащить три нужных мне числа. Однако индекс выходит за пределы массива.

Полагаю, что проблема в *sql_expression*. Каждый из трех запросов получает только один объект. Я думал, что в итоге будет получено три объекта, и я смогу присвоить их значения. На деле же, видимо, все происходит несколько иначе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string sql_expression = 
  "SELECT " + 
  "(SELECT id FROM store_assortment WHERE position_name = '" + pos + "') as f1," +
  "(SELECT id FROM thickness WHERE thickness_name = '" + thick + "') as f2," + 
  "(SELECT id FROM diametr WHERE diametr_name = '" + diam + "') as f3";
```

Параметризируйте SQL запросы - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection.